# Rails Mechanize - download file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, mechanize

I have filled in a form which when submitted should trigger the downloading of a file.
I tried saving the file in the following way:

```
mechanize.get(form.submit).save_as('file.csv')
```

However, this saves the page's source rather than a file.

How could I save the file when submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Mechanize::Download](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html).

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new
mechanize.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
# ... fill form
mechanize.get(form.submit).save('file.csv')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still downloads the page.